# Split jackson configuration into separate properties

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and would like to split my application.properties into separate files. There are already similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them seem to work for configuring Jackson.

My current non working solution is the following:

```
root/
- application.properties (without Jackson configuration)
- jackson-configuration.properties (includes Jackson configuration)
```

Jackson configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/jackson-configuration.properties")
public class JacksonConfiguration {

}
```

Please note, I've tried different ways to specify the path including:

- "/jackson-configuration.properties"
- "jackson-configuration.properties"
- "classpath:/jackson-configuration.properties"
- "classpath:jackson-configuration.properties"

Spring Boot does not seem to use the configuration. If I copy it over into the application.properties - it works.

Content of jackson-configuration.properties:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
spring.jackson.mapper.sort-properties-alphabetically=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
spring.jackson.parser.strict-duplicate-detection=true
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Zurich
```

My application is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` , so it should scan for additional properties.

**/edit**

I just realized the problem is the testing, not the productive code itself. If I start the application it works. What doess not work is testing with `@JsonTest`. I can fix this problem by adding the following line to my tests `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JacksonConfiguration.class})`. But in turn, this causes the annotation `@JsonComponent` to stop working but only for the `@JsonTest` annotated classes.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html). Here is an excerpt from the documentation

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or
>   @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, you must
>   ensure that an appropriate embedded value resolver is registered in
>   the BeanFactory used by the ApplicationContext. This happens
>   automatically when using  in XML. When
>   using @Configuration classes this can be achieved by explicitly
>   registering a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer via a static @Bean
>   method.

You need to create a bean like this

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   configurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("file:pathtToFile"));
   configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
   return configurer;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working. I added this method to the configuration class without an effect. I changed the file path to: classpath:/jackson-configuration.properties. I also tried it with file:jackson-configuration.properties. Unfortunately without success either. The configuration is simply ignored.

Comment: did u try to debug? is this piece of code being called during startup?

Comment: Actually my initial analysis was wrong. The initial code works without your proposed modification. Sorry for that. I'm testing the code with ```@JsonTest```. There it's not working. I can fix it by adding the annotation:
```@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JacksonConfiguration.class})``` but then the ```@JsonComponent``` annotation stops working.